# Undefined variable: model in yii dilema

Tags: php, yii

First of all, I checked other similar questions but they are different...

So I have the actionIndex() like:

```
 public function actionIndex()
 {
    $model = $this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->id);

    if(isset($_POST['Resellerdetails']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Resellerdetails'];
        if($model->save())
           $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Resellerdetails');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

and in index.php I have the following line:

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

The issue is that in _form.php I have the error: Undifiened Undefined variable: model on line:

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
```

from _form.php..

I var_dump() -ed the $model in _form.php and the variable exists and it's FULL not NULL :) I just can't understand why this is happening...

Can somebody assist? :-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out... I did not knew this but Yii does not allow a $dataProvider and a $modal var to be passed in render() method.

I just removed $dataProvider and now it works like a charm :)

Comment: That's not quite true. You can of course pass a data provider and a model to the view and even use it there. The error must be something other.

Comment: I also posted on Yii framework forum and no answer received... if not this, what else? Why did it worked if I removed $dataProvider? :-?